# What's the best Pandas apply / loop method in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, pandas

I'm transforming some applicant transactional data, and I need to create a new flag column (labeled as "DESIRED FLAG" in my example). However, I can't figure out the right looping/apply method as there can be so many different variations in the logic below.

In a perfect world, the sequential applicant process history would look like this, with all "Statuses" set to "Completed":

- On-Site Interview Kick Off --> Schedule Interviews --> Decision; OR
- Phone Interview Kick Off --> Schedule Interviews --> Decision

And of course, applicants can go through many phone interviews and on-sites during their applicant process.

As the example below shows, sometimes there are "Schedule Interviews" that are canceled. In those cases, I need to remove that step and the subsequent steps associated with that. These include "Schedule Interviews, "Decision", and "On-Site Interview Kick Off"OR"Phone Interview Kick Off". Also, sometimes there can be other "Events" like we see with the manually skipped one.

I have other types of scenarios that I need to create flags for, so I need to keep the original dataframe with just the new column.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Employee ID': ["100","100", "100", "100","100","100","100","100","100","100","200", "200", "200","200","200","200","200","300","300", "300", "300","300","300","300"],
        'Completed On Date': ["2009-01-01","2010-01-01","2011-06-05","2012-07-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01","2016-01-01","2017-01-01","2018-01-01","2010-01-01","2011-06-05","2012-07-01","2012-08-15","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01","2009-01-01","2010-01-01","2011-06-05","2012-07-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01"],
        'Event': ["Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","Phone Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","Decision","Phone Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","Job Apply","Phone Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision"],
        'Event Status': ["Completed","Completed","CANCELED","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","CANCELED","Manually Skipped","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","CANCELED","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed"],
        'DESIRED FLAG': ["Keep","Keep","Remove","Remove","Remove","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Remove","Remove","Remove","Remove","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Remove","Remove","Remove","Keep","Keep"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Employee ID','Completed On Date','Event','Event Status','DESIRED FLAG'])
df = df.sort_values(by=(['Employee ID','Completed On Date']))

df
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can post what the desired output looks like.

Comment: See the 'DESIRED FLAG' column. That is what the output should look like. Thanks!

Comment: Got it. Helps to have it in the form of a dataframe to visualize, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: Np. I never figured out how to output the DF in this forum! :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code solves your problem

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Employee ID': ["100","100", "100", "100","100","100","100","100","100","100","200", "200", "200","200","200","200","200","300","300", "300", "300","300","300","300"],
        'Completed On Date': ["2009-01-01","2010-01-01","2011-06-05","2012-07-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01","2016-01-01","2017-01-01","2018-01-01","2010-01-01","2011-06-05","2012-07-01","2012-08-15","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01","2009-01-01","2010-01-01","2011-06-05","2012-07-01","2013-01-01","2014-01-01","2015-01-01"],
        'Event': ["Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","Phone Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","Decision","Phone Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","Job Apply","Phone Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision","On-Site Interview Kick Off","Schedule Interviews","Decision"],
        'Event Status': ["Completed","Completed","CANCELED","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","CANCELED","Manually Skipped","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed","CANCELED","Completed","Completed","Completed","Completed"],
        'DESIRED FLAG': ["Keep","Keep","Remove","Remove","Remove","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Remove","Remove","Remove","Remove","Keep","Keep","Keep","Keep","Remove","Remove","Remove","Keep","Keep"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Employee ID','Completed On Date','Event','Event Status','DESIRED FLAG'])
df = df.sort_values(by=(['Employee ID','Completed On Date']))


index_list_delete = []
start_deleting = False
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    if start_deleting == False:
        # whenever I see a "CANCELED", i know some following rows need to be deleted
        if df.iloc[i]['Event Status'] == 'CANCELED':
            index_list_delete += [i]
            start_deleting = True
    else:
        # whenever i see a "Schedule Interviews", i need to stop deleting. 
        # otherwise keep track of the rows that need to be deleted
        if df.iloc[i]['Event'] == 'Schedule Interviews':
            start_deleting = False
        else:
            index_list_delete += [i]

# deleting rows
df = df.drop(df.index[index_list_delete])
# reseting index
df = df.reset_index(drop = True)
```

and you will get the following result

```
   Employee ID Completed On Date                       Event Event Status DESIRED FLAG
0          100        2009-01-01                    Decision    Completed         Keep
1          100        2010-01-01  On-Site Interview Kick Off    Completed         Keep
2          100        2014-01-01         Schedule Interviews    Completed         Keep
3          100        2015-01-01                    Decision    Completed         Keep
4          100        2016-01-01    Phone Interview Kick Off    Completed         Keep
5          100        2017-01-01         Schedule Interviews    Completed         Keep
6          100        2018-01-01                    Decision    Completed         Keep
7          200        2010-01-01  On-Site Interview Kick Off    Completed         Keep
8          200        2014-01-01         Schedule Interviews    Completed         Keep
9          200        2015-01-01                    Decision    Completed         Keep
10         300        2009-01-01                   Job Apply    Completed         Keep
11         300        2010-01-01    Phone Interview Kick Off    Completed         Keep
12         300        2014-01-01         Schedule Interviews    Completed         Keep
13         300        2015-01-01                    Decision    Completed         Keep
```

Comment: I did some additional testing with real data, and this logic doesn't limit itself to the Employee ID... It should perform your solution only within each respective employee ID set.

Comment: An inelegant and partial solution is below. In a subsequent step, I will still have to filter out the ones where the last step for them is Schedule Interview Team....

if (df.iloc[i]['Event Status'] == 'CANCELED') and (df.iloc[i]['Employee ID'] == df.iloc[i+1]['Employee ID']):